# C# - How to Save IntPtr Buffer Data to File (quickest way)?

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm using this code to save bytes from a IntPtr buffer in unmanaged code to file. It's a simple callback function:

```cs
private void callback(IntPtr buffer, int length)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
    Marshal.Copy(buffer, bytes, 0, length);
    FileStream file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    file.Write(bytes, 0, length);
    file.Close();
}
```

What I want is to store this data to file and throw it away. From what I understand there is a buffer in the unmanaged code and a 2nd one in MY code. I don't want to copy the data around I want it directly:

```cs
// bad:     (unmanaged) buffer -> (managed) bytes -> file
// awesome: (unmanaged) buffer ->                    file
```

For my task I need the most quickest way to store the data to file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's called "managed" for some reason :-)
What you can do though is declare [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services), like this:

```
private void callback(IntPtr buffer, int length)
{
    FileStream file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    int written;
    WriteFile(file.Handle, buffer, length, out written, IntPtr.Zero);
    file.Close();
}

 [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
 private static extern bool WriteFile(IntPtr hFile, IntPtr lpBuffer, int NumberOfBytesToWrite, out int lpNumberOfBytesWritten, IntPtr lpOverlapped);
```

Answer (score 18):

Staying within the .NET framework is probably better form than using calls to kernel dlls.

I would use:

```
private void callback(IntPtr buffer, int length, String filename)
{
    try
    {
        FileStream file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        UnmanagedMemoryStream ustream = new UnmanagedMemoryStream((byte*)buffer, length);
        ustream.CopyTo(file);
        ustream.Close();
        file.Close();
    }
    catch{/** To do: catch code **/}
}
```